# Как добавить картинку в галерею эмулятора андроид?

Tags: android, gallery, эмулятор

Я получил в ответ 2 варианта:
 1. adb push () (destination-path-remote).
 Где взять (destination-path-remote)?
 2. добавить картинку в sdcard. Что делать если нет прав для добавления в папку sdcard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20859733/3212712) галерея отображает картинки имеющиеся в системной БД с картинками. Добавить их туда можно, например, так:

```
public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Comment: Здесь можно указывать путь к картинке типа: C:\newFolder и т.д.? И где взять Context? Извините за глупые вопросы я новичек в андроид. Если есть ссылки на ответы пожайлуста бросайте.

Comment: @AndrewLawmaking, ну, вам сначала нужно картинку в файл записать. Можно по разному, в зависимотсти от того, как вы картинку получаете - фото камерой, ссылка, скриншот, собственноручно сделанный Bitmap, иконка из ресурсов etc. При этом нужно разрешение на запись и чтнение данных. Контекст же - это активити, сервис etc. Часто можно получить методом getContext из разных объектов

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение вроде получилось. Еще вопрос: можно ли выбрать несколько картинок с галереи и передать в imageview?

Comment: @AndrewLawmaking, можно. Но вопрос у вас очень расплывчатый - вам нужно потом переключение меж ними и если да, то какое? Или надо все вместе одновременно отобразить в одном виджете? Попробуйте чётко сформулировать вопрос и задать его в новом вопросе

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585445/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8-%D0%B2