# Можно ли передать несколько картинок одновременно с эмулятора андроид галереи в мое приложение?

Tags: android, gallery

У меня есть приложение в котором есть `ImageView`.

Я могу взять одну картинку с галереи с помощью:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

и передать ее в мое приложение в `ImageView`.

Можно ли сделать так, чтоб имелась возможность выбрать несколько картинок одновременно с галереи и передать их в мое приложение `ImageView`?

Если да, то как это сделать?

Если нет, предложите пожалуйста альтернативные варианты, если таковы имеются.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Вариантов несколько:

1. Добавить флаг `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`:

   ```
   photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
   ```

   **НО**, это вариант будет работать далеко не везде и, возможно, не так как надо.
2. Использовать стороннее решение вроде [этого](https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick) или [этих](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+multiple+image+picker&type=Repositories).
3. Написать свой диалог выбора картинок.

**Предпочтительнее** всего, на мой взгляд, вариант **номер 2**.

Comment: А как проверить первый вариант? Я ввел Extra_Allow_multiply, запустил приложение и как здесь выбрать несколько картинок? Я нажимаю на одну и она сразу сохраняется в imageView?

Comment: @AndrewLawmaking, Как я уже говорил, это не очень хорошее решение, которое работает не всегда. Лучше воспользуйтесь библиотекой из второго варианта.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо. А с видео также можно сделать? Например выбрать все видео с галереи и передать их в мое приложение?

Comment: @AndrewLawmaking, Да, можно, с помощью соответствующих библиотек, например.

Comment: если не сложно поделитесь ссылками пожайлуста

Comment: @AndrewLawmaking, https://github.com/tungdx/android-media-picker

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!